# linebreaking of name-year citation style in arxiv version

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, margins, natbib, arxiv

I was trying to submit a manuscript to the arXiv using the imsart package: see [here](http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html). I am using the name-year citation style, and it works well in my own tex compiler. However the version that the arXiv produces with my
latex file has references going well into the margin, which looks terrible. Is there any way to fix it? Below is the current version of my tex file.

```
\documentclass[aos]{imsart}

\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,enumerate,bm,makeidx,xcolor}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
....
\bibliographystyle{imsart-nameyear}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the name of the bibliography style file? Do you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: @Mico I used the imsart package...I have included details in the editted version of the question.

Comment: Things seem to compile fine if you add the option `authoryear` when loading the `natbib` package: `\RequirePackage[authoryear]{natbib}`.